# Path planning with potential field

Tags: mobile-robot

Can shortest path be computed using potential field path planning algorithm? Or is it just for obstacle avoidance and navigative towards goal? As i studied potential field deals with attracrive/repulsive forces, its not for shortest path finding.

Answer (score 2):

Potential field does not aim at computing the shortest path between two points.
Shortest paths often necessarily get infinitesimally close or touching obstacles. On the other hand, paths that potential fields generate are away from any obstacles, according to repulsive fields. Therefore, they are normally not the shortest ones.